# Powershell - Merging 2 CSVs together that have commas in data fields parsing one of the data commas as a separator

Tags: powershell, csv

I have 2 CSVs found in the `$mailboxPath` and `$mailboxStatisticsPath`. I am using this code to merge the two together. By merge I mean this:

The `$mailboxPath` CSV has 4 columns: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`. The `$mailboxStatisticsPath` CSV has 2 columns: `E`, `F`.

The merged CSV will have these columns: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`

I use this code to do so:

```
$csv1 = @(gc $mailboxPath)
$csv2 = @(gc $mailboxStatisticsPath)
$combinedMailbox = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $csv1.Count; $i++) {
    $combinedMailbox += $csv1[$i] + ', ' + $csv2[$i]
}
# Output to file
$combinedMailbox | Out-File "$dirname\CombinedMailbox.csv" -encoding default
```

In the `$mailboxStatisticsPath` file, the first column contains data that has a comma in it, for example: `Smith, John`. The second column also contains data that has a comma in it, for example: `513.4 KB (525,772 bytes)`.

When the code above runs, it takes the first column and treats the comma as separator, splitting the line `Smith, John` into `Smith` in column `E`, and `John` in column `F` which is not correct.

[image]

Why would it count the `Smith, John` comma as a separator, but the comma in the file size value as a part of the data and not handle it as a separator? Is it because there is a space after the comma in the first cell but not in the second?

If this is the case, how can I properly merge the two CSVs in the way I defined above without having the data split into multiple different cells based on whether there is a comma with a space or not?

**EDIT:**
Here is the full powershell script:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

# Connect to exchange online
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $UserCredential -ShowProgress $true

# Read the client name
$clientName = Read-Host 'Client name?'
$dirname = "sample_path\$clientName"

# Create folder
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $dirname

# Setup mailbox and mailbox statistics CSV paths. If they exist, remove them first.
$mailboxPath = "$dirname\Mailbox.csv"
$mailboxStatisticsPath = "$dirname\MailboxStatistics.csv"
rm $mailboxPath -ea ig
rm $mailboxStatisticsPath -ea ig

# Get the user mailbox data
$mailbox = Get-Mailbox
# Add client name as a property to the mailbox object
$mailbox | Add-Member -NotePropertyName ClientName -NotePropertyValue $clientName -Force
$mailbox | Select-Object Name, ArchiveStatus, ArchiveWarningQuota, ClientName, ProhibitSendQuota, ProhibitSendReceiveQuota | Export-Csv $mailboxPath -notypeinformation
# Get the user mailbox statistics data
$mailbox | select -expand userprincipalname | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select-Object DisplayName, TotalItemSize | Export-Csv $mailboxStatisticsPath -notypeinformation

#Import the CSVs
# Create an Empty Array
$csv1 = @(gc $mailboxPath)
$csv2 = @(gc $mailboxStatisticsPath)
$combinedMailbox = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $csv1.Count; $i++) {
    $combinedMailbox += $csv1[$i] + ', ' + $csv2[$i]
}
# Output to file
$combinedMailbox | Out-File "$dirname\CombinedMailbox.csv" -encoding default

# Delete the originals
# Remove-Item $mailboxPath
# Remove-Item $mailboxStatisticsPath
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
```

Sample data from `$mailboxStatisticsPath`:

```
"DisplayName","TotalItemSize"
"Smith, John","513.4 KB (525,772 bytes)"
```

Comment: Use `Import-Csv` instead of `gc`/`Get-Content`

Comment: Please update your question with a full sample line from `$mailboxStatisticsPath`, including the header line.

Comment: If you’re creating the CSV which seems likely you can export with a different delimiter as well

Comment: I suggest changing `', '` to `','`, but apart from that there's no obvious problem, given that the fields are _double-quoted_, which disambiguates _embedded_ `,` chars. from _syntactic_ ones.